# How to write this query using Laravel query builder? (I could get the same result using Laravel eloquent.)

Tags: laravel-8

```sql
SELECT *,
    SUM(num_hr) AS total_hr,
    attendances.empID AS empid
FROM attendances
LEFT JOIN addsalaryemployees
    ON addsalaryemployees.empID = attendances.empID
LEFT JOIN positions
    ON positions.id = addsalaryemployees.empPosition
GROUP BY attendances.empID
ORDER BY addsalaryemployees.empFirstName ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel documentation is pretty good, there is an entire section on the [`Query Builder`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) which I recommend you take a read through.

There are a few ways you could achieve your desired `SQL`, the following being just one.

```php
$query = DB::table('attendances')
    ->leftJoin('addsalaryemployees', 'addsalaryemployees.empID', '=', 'attendances.empID')
    ->leftJoin('positions', 'positions.id', '=', 'addsalaryemployees.empPosition')
    ->groupBy('attendances.empID')
    ->orderBy('addsalaryemployees.empFirstName')
    ->selectRaw('*, SUM(num_hr) AS total_hr, attendances.empID AS empid');
```

If you `dd($query->toSql())`, you'll get the following.

```sql
select *, SUM(num_hr) AS total_hr, attendances.empID AS empid 
from `attendances`
left join `addsalaryemployees` on `addsalaryemployees`.`empID` = `attendances`.`empID`
left join `positions` on `positions`.`id` = `addsalaryemployees`.`empPosition`
group by `attendances`.`empID`
order by `addsalaryemployees`.`empFirstName` asc
```